# Missing Certificate for NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-11, nvidia-geforce, trusted-root-certificates

## Intro

Hello.
Two days ago, I started trying to update my NVIDIA graphics card, on my Windows 11 laptop, but GeForce Experience kept failing to update it (it kept saying "installation failed". So, I downloaded the driver directly from NVIDIA, but when I ran the install file, it loaded for a very little bit and promptly just closed with no warning of anything. I then proceeded to uninstall everything related to NVIDIA on my PC. I used DDU and NVIDIA's cleanup tool. I then tried to reinstall GeForce Experience and it just said "An unknown error has occurred". I then tried to install the driver itself with the same problem of it quickly quitting. I did notice that when I ran either of the exe files, it would say "Publisher: Unknown".

### Suspected Problem

I realized that the problem I was having was almost identical to the issue that I had when trying to install McAfee a few months ago. The solution involved my tech support agent installing a certificate to my   ***trusted root certificates***   folder. Therefore, I am pretty sure I am missing some certificate. The issue might be larger than this, though.

## What I Have Already Tried

I tried installing the driver and GeForce Experience in  ***safe mode*** . 
I tried disabling my  ***antivirus*** . 
I tried running the following commands and then restarting.

- sfc /scannow
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- chkdsk /f /r *(no issues)*

I tried installing the following certificates from [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm).

- DigiCert TLS ECC P384 Root G5
- DigiCert TLS RSA4096 Root G5
- DigiCert CS ECC P384 Root G5

I am not very good at using   ***Event Viewer***  , but I saw nothing relevant under *Application*.
I am pretty sure that this is everything that I have tried, but if I remember something that I forgot, I'll add it here.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Related: [How to reset Windows trusted certificates store to its default](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/71313/1204)

Comment: @Robert Do you think that I could have a conflicting certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!
First, I ran the following command to get all certificates that Microsoft gives in updates.
*certutil -generateSSTFromWU roots.sst*

I then added all of the certificates in roots.sst to my trusted root certificates and restarted my PC.